# Github pull request exclude 'merge branch' commits

Tags: git, github

My pull request consists of several commits. Among these commits there are some in which I just merged the master to the branch. So my pull request looks like this:

```
Commits on Apr 1, 2015
  Fix issue1

Commits on Apr 2, 2015
  Fix issue2

Commits on Apr 3, 2015
  Fix issue1
  Fix issue2
  Merge branch 'mybranch' of...
```

I would need only to have commits **Fix issue1** and **Fix issue2** from *Apr 3* in my pull request, and want to get rid of the
merge branch commits. Merge branch commits are not needed since those are already there in the upstream where I want to pull.
Github doesn't provide me an interface to cherry pick commits from an existing pull request..
What is the best practice to deal with this situation?

Comment: You're looking for `git rebase`

Answer (score 0):

If you have a commit that already in your target branch fell free to commit, nothing will actually be committed since its already in the target branch.

Next time you can use git `hunks` to add only the things that you need.

```
git add -p
```

it will open editor with the options to only add what you want to add.